# Which event i must use?

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
 htmlDiv+="<DIV class='addon-checkbox' 
   onclick='event.stopPropagation();__toogleEnabled(\""+__addons[i]+"\", this);'
   if (localStorage[\"__Enable__\"+__addons[i]]==\"yes\")
     this.style.backgroundPosition= \"0 -50px\"; >";
```

and when click on this div `function __toogleEnabled` correctly change background-position of image, but rest code do nothing.
I guess that `this`(receive current element) or whole instruction

```
if(localStorage[\"__Enable__\"+__addons[i]]==\"yes\")
             this.style.backgroundPosition= \"0 -50px\"; >";
```

dont work because there is no event. But i dont know what event must be.
May be it can be fix with another solution. I just want that `background-position` have value "0 -50px" , `if localStorage[\"__Enable__\"+__addons[i]]` have value `"yes" when page loaded` , but it must be done only for current div because there are many other div with same class and without id.

Comment: That is the absolute worst possible way to add a `<div>` with events. Use the DOM. Decouple your JavaScript from your markup. Assign events afterwards. Use classes instead of `style`. (Use fewer double-underscores?)

Comment: code like that is a nightmare to maintain or debug or test

Comment: Put your JS jobs into a function then bind this function to the `onclick` event of your `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting your quotes mixed up.  Your code needs to be changed to:

```
 htmlDiv+='<div class="addon-checkbox" '+
     'onclick="event.stopPropagation();__toogleEnabled(\''+__addons[i]+'\', this);'+
     'if(localStorage[\'__Enable__\'+__addons[i]]==\'yes\')'+
     'this.style.backgroundPosition=\'0 -50px\';" >';
```

But a much better way to do all this would be to use the DOM.

Comment: Still same result. A cant use DOM because i use personalized web chrome extension and ingect code to page what i need.

Comment: Why don't you have `__toogleEnabled` do the background switching.  If you did, it would be easier to debug and `console.log` some some stuff.